# Can't modify or delete as root?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, root

I can't modify the permissions of `/proc/sys`, it says `Operation not permitted` or `Permission denied`. Even as `root`! 
My `/` filesystem has been mounted `rw` and is `btrfs`. I tried `chattr`, but that doesn't work. (I guess it only works for `ext`?)
Current permissions are `dr-xr-xr-x`. (owner root group root)

What must I do?

Comment: why do you need to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/proc` filesystem does not store actual files or directories. It's just a view of the system in a way that resembles a filesystem. For example: each process is a directory, whose name is its PID. If you enter one of those directories, you will find a lot of files with information about that process: opened files, memory map, current working directory, nice level, uptime, etc. Some of this information can be gathered by just cat'ing a particular file inside the directory associated to the process. Some other is not human-readable but can be read by some other tools, like `top` and `ps`.

That said, I think you cannot modify permissions on `/proc/sys` (unless you modify the kernel). In my system, they have permission `555`. That is, no write allowed. And that is because you cannot add or delete files. All you can do is read from some of them, and write on some of them, but what you read or write is not stored in any storage medium, but are configuration options, or information, about the kernel, devices and processes.

You can add a new directory or file to `/proc` by writting a kernel module that uses the /proc interface (read about it in the book *Linux Device Drivers, 3rd ed.*)

Answer (score 2):

`/proc/sys` is not a real filesystem. It does not contain files which you could delete. It gives you information about your system via a filesystem-like interface so it is easy to access it with scripts/programs/command line tools, but it doesn't support deleting.

Read more on [procfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) page on Wikipedia.